# Use existing windows install as wine's virtual environment

Tags: wine

I currently have 2 drives in my pc one with windows and one with ubuntu would it be possible to use my windows drive as the environment wine uses so I can run all my programs installed on my windows drive in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's feasible to run some Windows program from their original locations, i.e. on the NTFS Windows partition, using wine. That said, a few *caveats*:

1. Though some Windows programs run well under wine, e.g. IrfanView and 7-Zip, some don't. See the [wine database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) for compatibility.
2. Some programs write to the NTFS partition, which can occasionally be problematical.
3. To use the programs, Ubuntu needs to mount the Windows NTFS partition. It can be set to be mounted automatically, but will **not** be mounted if Windows uses  Hibernation.
4. Making a wine application the default for handling a mime type is more involved than doing so for a native Linux app. You'll need to create your own .desktop files.

Some other options are available.

- Copy the program folder from C:\Program Files, or the (...x86) folder, to the Ubuntu *home* folder.
- Keep data in the Windows NTFS directory partition, but install a Linux version of the application and point it to that data. *Calibre*, for example, is available for Ubuntu.
- Look for Ubuntu *snap* versions of the Windows application. IrfanView, for example, is available in *snap*. Note that a *snap* version may be several generations behind the Windows version, though.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late but anyway ...
Sometimes to run windows installed programs on linux (wine), you just need to run the executable file (.exe) with wine. Go to the installation path and double click on it, that's it. There's no need to copy whole installation folder to wine virtual drive.
I tried this for Photoshop, InDesign, Foxit PDF editor and IDM and it worked.